# Is it possible to get current Unity container inside controller

Tags: c#, unity-container

I registered unity container like this:

```
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<ICacheManager, CacheManager>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```

Is it possible to get access to this "container" from controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing this which I often do for convenience is to declare your container as a global variable in your Global.ascx.cs file like:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static UnityContainer Container;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
         // assuming your initialize here
    } 
}
```

However this is fairly hack-ish.

The correct thing to do would be to use Unity to resolve your Controllers ([See this article on creating a unity controller factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvcdependencyinjection_topic2.aspx)), and then allow unity to inject any dependencies into your controller when it resolves the controller.

So a controller like:

```
public MyController: Controller {

 public ICacheManager CacheManager {get;set;}

}
```

Would automagically resolver any dependencies that your container has registered.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure why you need that, but here's the code:

```
public ActionResult Area51()
    {
        var _service = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof (IDummyService));

        return View();
    }
```

If what you are trying to do is injecting a Controller, you should set DepedencyResolver to use your IoC container in Global.asax's application start. Then, MVC will inject dependency to your controller automatically.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Look here for more example:

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/dependencyinjection/632V140413-Dependency-Injection-in-ASP.NET-MVC-4-using-Unity-IoC-Container.html

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you're resolving some Controller instance using the container. If that's the case, you can have the controller receive the IUnityContainer as a dependency just like any other.

What are you trying to accomplish? Getting the container in your resolved classes is not great because it couples your classes with the container, and can usually be replaced with other mechanisms.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        var foo = container.Resolve<MyController>();
    }
}

public class MyController
{
    private IUnityContainer container;

    public MyController(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although it is possible to that, it's best that you avoid it.

It's best that you take any dependencies the controller needs via constructor parameters. This way, the class (controller) makes it clear what are the dependencies required for it to run.

If configured correctly, the container will provide those dependencies and their dependencies (if any), and so on.

The usage of an IoC container should typically be restricted to only one place inside an application (called the *composition root*). Any extra reference/call to the container is susceptible to lead to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). See the linked article for reasons why such an approach may be bad.

Comment: Given this "Service Locator anti-pattern", how does one utilize the container Resolve without a Service Locator to resolve the container???

Comment: @enorl76 Your calls to `container.Resolve()` should be restricted to one place in the application, as I described in the answer. Your business components should be unaware that they and their dependencies are being injected.

Comment: The issue i'm wondering about is when a business component needs another only during certain workflow, but I believe the answer is probably refactoring the business components slightly where the certain workflow would be encapsulated in a business component with an explicit constructor with the sister business-component as a constructor dependency.

Comment: @enorl76 I think most containers support such a scenario. I use StructureMap and named registrations for cases like these.

Comment: I get sick of 'anti-answers', rather than answering a question, questioning the motives of the OP.

Comment: @DougBeard If the question is "How do i use a hammer on a screw?" it is good to remind people that there are also screwdrivers out there.

Comment: @w0lf I get that.  Remind them and then answer the question asked if it can be answered.  Sometimes one maybe nailing a screw for a very good reason.

Comment: I agree with your stance, I'm just trying to figure out how to maintain single composition when you need an instance of the object scoped to a new child container. (e.g. when using `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`) -- google lead me here -- guess I'll keep looking.