# How do I resolve type dependencies in regards of controller action?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, asp.net-mvc-5

**Update**

I've managed to create something that is satisfactory. You can see the relevant parts of the code [here on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/ggxsAhUn). If there is there something that I could improve please let me know. I've got a nagging feeling this isn't very efficient.

**Clarification**

While it certainly seems to work with static dependencies as suggested by `d_z`, I was hoping, to avoid instantiating objects not utlilized, that I could use something similar to this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  [Dependency]
  protected IBaseData ActionData { get; set; }

  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View(ActionData);
  }

  public ActionResult About()
  {
    return View(ActionData);
  }
}
```

The data in the `IndexData` and `AboutData` instances in reality aren't static. The instance properties are set with data from a database. The DbProvider is injected into these classes.

In the end what I want is to minimize the memory footprint and database accesses.

**Original**

Let's say we have the following basic controller (with corresponding views):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  public ActionResult About()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

We also have two classes with the same interface:

```
public class IndexData : IBaseData
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Index { get; set; }

  public IndexData()
  {
    Name = "Index";
    Index = "This is an Index instance";
  }
}

public class AboutData : IBaseData
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string About { get; set; }

  public AboutData()
  {
    Name = "About";
    About = "This is an About instance";
  }
}
```

What I'd like is for **Unity** to inject an instance of one of these classes, depending on which action is executed, into the *corresponding view*. I've tried to get my head around how to achieve this but I'm stumped. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you wish to use those classes inside your `HomeController`?

Comment: Your confusing when the dependency injection with your application behavior. DI should happen regardless of which action your're going to call. You can achieve what you need by using a factory, injecting that & calling it to make the appropriate data class

Comment: @Steven: It's not in the controller I want to use them. I'd like to use them in the views and hence bind the correct model to the correct view, IndexData to the IndexView and AboutData to the AboutView, using dependency injection.

Comment: @SimonHalsey: So my requirements are not possible then with DI? I should stick with factory pattern?

Comment: Pretty much. When you create an instance of a class (ie your controller) you should be able to use any method or property on the class. if you design the class so you need to know which methods can/can't run when you instantiate it, you've got a bad design where you either use a factory, or split the class up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are requesting makes little sense. Dependency Injection is about injecting (design time) behavior (a.k.a. services). What you are trying to do however is to inject runtime data. So this is not a task that yout IoC container should handle.

Next the view should be completely ignorant of any dependency injection. The controller should return all data that the view needs from its action method. Make sure that your `About` and `Index` action methods return the proper instance.

Comment: I don't agree with the statement that IoC shouldn't handle runtime behavior. Sometimes it's pretty useful, however I consider it rare.

Comment: @d_z: Letting the container inject runtime data makes it very hard (or even impossible) to have a DI configuration that is verifiable. Not being able to verify the configuration in a simple integration test or during app startup, will make the configuration very fragile, and means you will have to click through the entire application to check whether your configuration is correct.

Comment: I manage to get it working to my liking. Tried to follow your advise as far as I could. I created a [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/ggxsAhUn) with the relevant code. Is there something else I could improve.

Comment: @user3564235: In your `UnityControllerFactory.CreateController`, don't fall back to calling the base behavior in case of an exception, because that will hide the real problem. Save yourself a lot of headackes and let the exception simply bubble up. Also prevent letting  your repositories take a dependency on the container, that leads to the Service Locator anti-pattern. Also -if possible-, prevent having a base class (BaseController) that implements shared behavior or cross-cutting concerns. Having a base class just for the translations seems unneeded and  only complicate matter.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'll have a look at your suggestions. Regarding the `BaseController`. The PasteBin example is dumbed down example of the "real thing" which is much more complex and a base class is actually preferred. I included it in the example so that you could see the full object graph and all relevant relations and dependencies.

Comment: @user3564235: My point still stands. Prevent using base classes. They tend to become god objects that violate SRP and have severe maintenance issues.

Comment: So with 10+ controllers I should duplicate `ITranslationRepository` and have the exact same override on `OnActionExecuting` in each class? That doesn't sound legitimate.

Comment: @user3564235: That's not what I said. Take a look at this alternative: http://pastebin.com/MEqHHgTJ. In this approach the view models are dumb DTOs (no behavior) and building the view models is extracted to the `IActionViewModelProvider` class, which removes the need for the base class.

Comment: I see your point. However, as the "real thing" is much more complex and the `TranslationProvider` is not only used in the ViewModels but also translates for other Actions (json serialized data). So it's still needed at controller level. Why should I create a factory for the ViewModels (`ActionViewModelProvider`, there are more than one ActionViewModel as per my example). In my current approach I let Unity do the hard work. I don't even need to specify the ViewModel type. I could just `return View(ActionViewModel)` and Unity would resolve it correctly. Maybe I'm overthinking this. It's late and

Comment: ...I need to get some sleep. Love your input though! From only having heard of IoC and DI on monday I now can say I'm atleast at 1% of understanding the concepts. ;)

Comment: Woke up this morning with new insight and can now see things more clearly. There is no need to inject the `ActionViewModels`. In fact removing DI from the ActionViewModels simplifies the `TranslationRepository` and removes it's dependency on the IoC container. Now there is no need to configure Unity to resolve the different `ActionViewModels` since the factory creates them. Unit test are also more easy to implement and there are no hidden dependencies. Well played sir, well played indeed.

Comment: @user3564235: A good night sleep can really help putting things in perspective. I speak from experience :-)

Answer (score 0):

To register several mappings for a type in Unity you have to create *named* registration like this:

```
myContainer.RegisterType<IBaseData, IndexData>("Index");
myContainer.RegisterType<IBaseData, AboutData>("About");
```

So after this in your actions you can resolve an instance accordingly:

Index:

```
IBaseData data = myContainer.Resolve<IBaseData>("Index");
```

About:

```
IBaseData data = myContainer.Resolve<IBaseData>("About");
```

Or for static dependencies it works like this:

```
[Dependency("Index")]
IBaseData data { get; set; }
```

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664762%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) for details

Comment: While static dependencies seem to work it forces me to instantiate every xxxData class. This would have an impact on the memory footprint and database accesses. (See my edited question).

Comment: Then go with `IBaseData data = myContainer.Resolve<IBaseData>("Index");` :)

Comment: And how/where exactly do I do that? I don't have a reference to `myContainer`.

Comment: @user3564235, To answer I'll need to know how you create it :)

Comment: In the default `UnityConfig` class that is created when adding the `Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC` NuGet package (`Unity.Mvc`). Nothing changed from stock, except for the added `RegisterType`s' of course.

Comment: @user3564235, Here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231236/is-it-possible-to-get-current-unity-container-inside-controller) is the answer

Comment: I figured as much and implemented a new ControllerFactory. Still struggling to get Unity to resolve automatically in the factory. If not successful then I'll resolve it as suggested in the controller.

Comment: This answer is bad for several reasons, most of all because you couple your application to a specific DI framework using the [Dependency] attributes and the calls to `myConteainer.Resolve`, and this leas to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Also the use of named registrations over complicates the configuration, while you still not address the source of the problem, which is the use of runtime data into the object graph.

Comment: @Steven, Whoa! That was supposed to be a technical answer, not architectural. I can't make judgments about design because I see very little of it and more importantly, I wasn't asked for. Using named dependencies has drawbacks, I agree, but it's just a tool. To use it or not is a decision which we have to make.

Comment: I manage to get it working to my liking. Tried to follow your advise as far as I could. I created a [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/ggxsAhUn) with the relevant code. Is there something else I could improve.