# How to get current IUnityContainer to register more types

Tags: unity-container

I have a windows service that is using Microsoft's Unity `2.1`, typically all the types are registered during the service startup. (program.cs)

There is also a Windows Service Class. I need to get access to current `IUnityContainer` in this service class to register a type.

How do i get access to `IUnityContainer` so that i can register more types?

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of *Current IUnityContainer* as you can have multiple of these, even though this is a very rare thing, in my experience, if you don't count the child containers. There are however multiple ways you can keep a hold on your container though. You can do what's suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231236/is-it-possible-to-get-current-unity-container-inside-controller), by doing that at a higher level, but I'd recommend against it. What I've taken a habit of doing is:

In the non-main projects, I create a static class such as:

```
static class UnityRegistrator
{
    public static void Register(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // Whatever Registrations for types in this assembly.
        container.RegisterType<INamedClass, ClassLibrary2>(
            new InjectionConstructor(
                new ResolvedParameter<string>("Foo")));
    }
}
```

And in the main project, for example in your `program.cs`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();


        MyAssembly.UnityRegistrator.Register(container);

        var namedClass = container.Resolve<INamedClass>();
        namedClass.Whatever();
    }

    static void Register(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // Whatever Registrations for types in this assembly.
        container.RegisterType<string>("Foo", "Bar");
    }
}
```